# Remove [identification-request] from front page when not logged in

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, tags, identification-questions

So as i was waiting for Windows to Update i was messing around on the main page  while i was logged and look what i saw

[image]

i get the feeling new users see [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) and think we still use it but ignore the error that pop up about us blacklisting it (which they shouldn't).

is there any way we can remove [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) tag from here?

Comment: Oh dayum! We should have fixed that a long time ago. This is awkward.

Comment: Seems like it's taking tags directly from [here](http://anime.stackexchange.com/tags), sorted by popularity. And we do have almost 400 of them, making them the 3rd most popular type of question on the site still, even after post-ban cleanup.

Comment: Posted to Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286105/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess someone fixed this - JNat marked [the post on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286105/) as [status-completed], and indeed, [identification-request] is no longer listed as one of the tags on the front page for non-logged-in users.

[image]

And it didn't even take 6-8 weeks! Great stuff; my thanks to the folks at SE.

Comment: to correct you. it has been 6 weeks since i posted the Meta

Answer (score 4):

The tag is there because its on almost 400 questions. You'll need to remove it from those -- there's no specific way of preventing a blacklisted tag from appearing in the home page list, except making it less popular.